# conntrack -E - traffic counter reporting

Tags: ip, monitoring, bandwidth, ip-conntrack

I'm currently in the process of writing small solution which would continuously receive output from `conntrack -E` command and along with some other stats, it would count/monitor traffic.

The only problem/challenge I face is that, "conntrack -E" reports packets and byte counters only for *DESTROY* events. *UPDATE* events don't seem to update "incremental" counters. If, for example, I would like to cut-off some device from network at certain limit, somebody could (theoretically) keep the TCP connection opened indefinitely and in that way bypass the limit hit.

I seek your advice on how to mitigate this situation. I was thinking that maybe lowering the TCP keepalive interval in kernel to 10 minutes could be a solution, but I'm not sure that I see all possible implications of that.

P.S. I know that I could go with other possible solutions like [ulogd2](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/) or something similar, but I would prefer the way I imagined at the beginning :)